# First Kid, new born Checklist for the first 3 months and delivery in United States

Tags: infant, newborn, car-seat

I am a first time parent with still 6 months out from the delivery date. I am in the United States. I am making a list of items and things figured out that are a must have for the day of delivery and things I need to do to prepare for up to three months after the birth. Where can I find a checklist for resources and steps that are essential to prepare for my baby?

Here is an example of the kind of checklist I am looking for:
https://www.oviahealth.com/guide/10340/packing-a-hospital-bag

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93704/discussion-on-question-by-pal4life-first-kid-new-born-checklist-for-the-first-3).

Answer (score 1):

There are many lists of what's "needed" because everyone has their own idea of what they needed and have decided to share their list.  As a parent you need to identify the needs from the wants.  What you need is related to keeping your child alive and loved.  What you want is focused on luxuries like higher quality products and services.

While there is nothing wrong with luxuries, you risk wasting a lot of money preparing with the right motion sensitive high frequency vibration guaranteed sleep rocker contraption when you realize your child hates it.

Keep it simple and increase what you use incrementally as you learn your child and yourself.

1. How does mom want to give birth? Build a birth plan.
2. How will you transport your child? Get a car seat.
3. What doctor are you going to take your child to?
4. Make sure to register your child under your insurance (if applicable).
5. How are you going to feed your child?
6. Determine where your baby will sleep and bedding situation
7. Get clothes and diapers for your baby
8. Child-proof your living space

Your wants will change, but your child will always need to eat, sleep and be safe.

Comment: Thanks for the response, Birth plan - never heard of that one before - like this ? - https://www.whattoexpect.com/pregnancy/labor-and-delivery/birth-plan/

Comment: @pal4life You got it, that's exactly what I'm talking about.  Making a plan helped my wife and I immensely by having our thoughts and desires expressed in writing before the chaos of labor and delivery arrived.

Comment: Don't forget entertainment for long labors. My best friends brought a SNES to play Mario to pass the 22-hour labor time.

Comment: You don't need to do #8 until the baby can move unless you have knives dangling from the ceiling. I recommend you do #3 in the 3rd trimester and you need to have a pediatrician before your baby is born, because you need to schedule your first appointment 1-2 days after the delivery. #5 Even you and your partner are planning to nurse, I still recommend having formula on hand. My wife didn't make enough milk for my son to where he lost too much weight and we supplemented with formula.

Comment: #7 and baby wipes!